# Why isnt the "completed" classname not working when i check it off as completed. I can see it is being toggled to true but somehow the classname isnt

Tags: javascript, css

I can see its changing to completed but the css isnt working anyone can help me please. `{completed: true, id: 1288.4902006789644, text:...}`

this is the code

```
 <div className="todo">
      <li className={'todo-item $ {todo.completed ? "completed" : ""}'}>
        {text}
      </li>
      <button onClick={completehandler}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
      </button>
      <button onClick={deletehandler}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} />
      </button>
    </div>
```

this is the CSS

```
.completed{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `backtick`  , you should change `'` with backtick ` and you should remove space between $ and {

Comment: I changed it to backticks and it doesn't work <li className={`todo-item $ {todo.completed ? "completed" : ""}`}>

Comment: It's `${` and not `$ {`!

Comment: Also you should remove space like @CherryDT mentioned